# What can the mouse do more efficiently than the keyboard in vim?

Tags: vim, mouse

If add `set mouse=a` in vimrc then the user can use the mouse, but I wonder what can it do while how great keyboard shortcuts is. Is there anything the mouse can do but the keyboard not?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, everything that can be done with the mouse can be done with the keyboard. Using the mouse in Vim is mostly a reflex inherited from… every other applications.

The only thing I can think of that is easier with the mouse than with the keyboard is resizing windows.

`{count}<C-w><` sucks hard because of all the typing and thinking required; grabbing the separator and moving it around with the mouse is probably marginally quicker but a lot more convenient in my opinion.

Comment: +1 but I'd like to add that using the mouse/keyboard is far more efficient in getting you RSI than only using a keyboard :)